# Euclid's Proof of infinite prime numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I think this should probably be obvious, but I having trouble understanding part of the proof:
If $N=p_1p_2\cdots p_n+1$, then why is it necessarily true that any given $p$ does not divide $N$?

Comment: Because it leaves a remainder of $1$.

Comment: Dividing by any of the given $p_k$ leaves a remainder of $1$.

Comment: Oh alright I see thanks

Comment: You can also use $\, N = p_1 p_2\cdots p_k +\, p_{k+1}\cdots p_n,\ \ $ or, more simply, note that $N(N+1)$ has more prime factors than $N.\ \ $

Comment: Caveat: Note that this does not _generate all_ prime numbers, only creates a new one. For example, $2 \cdot 3 + 1 = 7 $, but the next prime is $5$.

Answer (score 2):

Because the rest of division for all $p_{i}$ is $1$. For example we can suppose that there are only $3$ prime numbers: $(2,3,5)$. So you can define a new number $N$ as $2*3*5+1=31$. So it results that $31=2*15+1=6*5+1=3*10+1$. Then $N$ is a new prime number!

Comment: Or is divisible by a new prime number, in general.